# LocationManager getProviders(true) not returning providers

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, locationmanager

OK so basically I want to start listening for a single update from a `BroadcastReceiver`, and for some reason all the providers are disabled from my access.  Here is the code snippet

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
                            context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
String majorProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
Log.d("location test", "major provider " + majorProvider);
List<String> allProviders = locationManager.getAllProviders();
for(int i=0; i < allProviders.size();i++) {
    Log.d("location test", "provider " + i + ": " + allProviders.get(i));
}
Log.d("location test", "enabled...");
allProviders = locationManager.getProviders(true);
for(int i=0; i < allProviders.size();i++) {
    Log.d("location test", "enabled provider " + i + ": " + allProviders.get(i));
}
```

and my logcat results

```
04-09 11:23:35.763: D/location test(32576): major provider null
04-09 11:23:35.763: D/location test(32576): provider 0: network
04-09 11:23:35.763: D/location test(32576): provider 1: passive
04-09 11:23:35.763: D/location test(32576): provider 2: gps
04-09 11:23:35.763: D/location test(32576): enabled...
```

I am guessing that the issue is that I am calling all of this from a `BroadcastReceiver`, but I tried passing it context from somewhere else.  Is it not possible to access LocationManager from a `BroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: all providers are enabled or not...?

Comment: @sandy they were all disabled, it was simply a forgotten permission

Comment: I had similar issue (with proper permission in manifest.xml) and solved it by calling request permission dialog. See https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wow I feel like such an idiot.  Well guys it was simply a permission issue.  If anyone runs across this again then just add the use permissions to manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: I have the permission in my app (including asking during runtime) and still having problems. :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, besides permission declarations in manifest, you may also need to manually ask user for location related permissions. And after permissions are granted, call `getProviders| getBestProvider`.

```
String[] perms = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};    
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, perms, REQ_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
```